# VB.NET - Add to a ComboBox on Form1 using a module, reference to non-shared member requires object reference

Tags: vb.net, forms, module, reference

Been a while since I've done any visual basic work. This problem has had me stumped for the best part of the day. I remember VB.net being much easier in the past...

The problem I am having is I need a module to change/add to an object on Form1. For the sake of this posted question I will be using "adding" an item to a ComboBox that is located on Form1 by using a function inside of a module.

Simple example of code:

FORM1

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'startup stuff
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MyFuction1()
  End Sub

End Class
```

MODULE1

```
Module Module1
  Public Function MyFunction1()
    Form1.ComboBox1.Items.Add("Test")
  End Function
End Module
```

When doing this I get the error:

```
reference to non-shared member requires object reference.
```

I have tried the following in Module1 with no dice.

```
Dim Frm1 As Form1
Frm1 = New Form1
Frm1.ComboBox1.Items.Add("Test")
```

Tried a few other things, been so long though I can't remember/post them all.

There has to be a way to use a module to complete the task I need. Please no responses that say "Do not use modules"...

I get the same error if I use a private, shared, or public function within Form1 as well.

I wanted to post the code as simple as possible without custom names to any objects. That way if the question is answered and works, future people spending hours on google that last here will more easily implement the answer into their own works.

Thank you for any and all help,
Donnie

Comment: Why is it essential that code dealing with a form instance object be in a Module?  Why put code dealing with controls anywhere but in that form?

Comment: You might want to have a look at Partial classes. This way, you can split the definition of Form1 into several files. For example in a program I wrote, I had the UI related code in the 1st file, code to handle emails in another file and helper code in yet another file. They were all still within the Form1 class declaration.

Comment: David, You sir are a life saver. And can still have the groups of functions, although ill use subs instead as another use posted, separated into different files and in folders within my solution explorer to help keep the coding need. and not having to scroll through every line just to find one set of code to change/fix. I'll post the solution that worked for me using partial classes

Comment: Also, you could have a look at #region as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking is a tailored interface to 'do things' in your form from other code.

```
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'startup stuff
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MyFuction1()
  End Sub

  Public Sub AddItemToComboBox1(TheThing as String) ' This is what you need
    ComboBox1.Items.Add(TheThing)
  End Sub
End Class
```

And then in the Module

```
Module Module1

  Public Sub TestAddThingToComboBox1()
  Dim Frm1 As Form1
    Frm1 = New Form1
    Frm1.AddItemToComboBox1("Test")
  End Sub
End Module
```

Why? The point of OOP encapsulating is that the working level detail is ... well ... encapsulated and the user gets to work with well defined interfaces. Form controls are part of the working level detail. Also, you can add input validation and other cool code in the interface, or manage the data better (e.g. re-ordering the ComboBox).

As an aside - use a `Sub` instead of a `Function` when there is no intention to return a value. Safer coding, you can't accidently assign it to something.

Comment: Ummm.. won't `Frm1 = New Form1` create an instance of the Form1 class that is separate from the default instance of Form1?

Comment: was hoping to use modules for groups of functions dealing with category. The project I am working on, each module would have quite a few functions. Just helps keep code easier IMO. But i know i did not have this problem a few years back. Nothing happens when I follow this code.

Comment: only thing i did different was change button click to TestAddThingToComboBox1() to try an initiate the sub in the module, did not do anything. If i can't use modules for this, I'd really rather use them, then thats fine i guess.

Answer (score 0):

FORM1.VB

```
Partial Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'startup stuff
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MyFunction1()
End Sub
End Class
```

MODULE1.VB

```
Partial Class Form1
Public Sub MyFunction1()
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("Test")
End Sub
End Class
```

module1.vb is no longer a module, but with the splitting files, I can still use it the way I intended to use modules.